# Open source Java Chess engine?

Tags: java, chess

I'm looking for a Chess Engine written in Java.  Google turns up a bunch of dead projects.  It doesn't have to be "smart", just know the basic rules and be able to run fast. I want to write my own graphics/interface on top of it.

Comment: Off topic but google gnuchess its pretty much what you want.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be "Java" as long as it has a usable interface or even a dll that can be interfaced with JNA or JNI.

Comment: It has to be "Java", gnuchess doesn't compile cleaning on android and other platforms.

Comment: chesspresso is nice.....http://www.chesspresso.org/

Answer (score 3):

[Carballo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/carballo/) is a project <strike>that's still in development</strike>, but it seems like it has promise.

Comment: It's a dead project.t  No source is provided.  It's class files are obfuscated.

Comment: Sorry. I Didn't look closely enough, I guess.

Comment: Look for Mediocre chess... one of the strongest ones around, free and open source.